# How to restore In-view Sketch Toolbar?

Tags: solidworks

My in-view sketch toolbar has disappeared recently -

[image]

How can you make this reappear? So confused, don't even know what it's name is!

Comment: maybe [here](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/43224) helps

Comment: Thanks for the lead Sam, I browsed on quite rigorously through the options listed there. I think I may have clicked every 'Reset' option possible now, nothing has worked though! Yikes, thoughts?

Comment: Contact Sketch...

Comment: What is your reference here?

Comment: The Grabcad is a website you can probably find the answer, there are many solidworks expert there, it never happend before to me bizarre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple, select '*View->Toolbars->View(Heads-Up)*' from the toolbar -

[image]

lol

Answer (score 1):

To reset the default toolbar to its original tool set, select Toolbar Options > Add or Remove Buttons > Main Toolbar > Reset Toolbar, or on the Customize dialog box'sToolbars tab, select Main Toolbar and click the Reset mbutton. From the menu bar, select View > Customize Toolbar.